# Virtual method refers dynamic or static type?

Tags: c#, virtual

As a brand new in .NET, just to clarify to myself:

virtual method refers to the dynamic or static object type?

```
Base myObject = new Derived();
myObject.Foo();
```

Foo() of derived class is invoked (assume that Foo() is virtual in Base and overridden in Derived)?

Comment: can you be more clear please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

The terms "static" and "dynamic" type are wrong here. Everything here is statically typed.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't Base the static type and Derived is dynamic one?

Comment: No. Base is the base type and Derived is the derived one. Static and dynamic typing are different to polymorphism.

Comment: Misunderstood, `**Base** instance = new _Derived_();`, isn't the bold type is the static and the italic the dynamic?

Comment: No. Your usage of the terms are incorrect. I would suggest you look up dynamic typing, static typing and polymorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since `Foo()` is overridden, it's the Derived class' Foo() you are going to call!

I'm quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y01k918.aspx)

> A virtual function is a member function that you expect to be
>   redefined in derived classes. When you refer to a derived class object
>   using a pointer or a reference to the base class, you can call a
>   virtual function for that object and execute the derived class's
>   version of the function.

Comment: So the dynamic type is the determining factor? In case of `Base base = new Base();` the Foo() in Base will be called? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the function `Foo()` in Base is called, if you instantiate the object to Base.